# How to change the Auth Guard in Laravel Auditing?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have used the Laravel Auditing plugin (http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/3.1) to log the all models changes.Am using different auth system but the  Laravel Auditing

> getLoggedInUserId()

using laravel core one so need to change that. i have forked this plugin and edited the function directly its worked. But i like to find another ways if you have idea share with me ?

```
 protected function getLoggedInUserId()
    {
        try {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                return Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, until version 4 of the package, you couldn't change the user resolver without modifying the actual code.

However, from version 4 onwards, you can do so in the configuration file (`config/audit.php`).

The user resolver can be set in two ways.

As a `Closure`:

`return [
    'user' = [
        'resolver' => function () {
            return Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier() : null;
        },
    ],
];`

As a FQCN:

`return [
    'user' = [
        'resolver' => App\User::class,
    ],
];`

> **TIP:** You have to implement the `OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\UserResolver` interface in the `App\User` class for this to work.

See the full documentation [here](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/4.0/general-settings).

Comment: yes  i got the solution from  https://github.com/owen-it/laravel-auditing/issues/175 :)